# PyQGIS XYZ tiles do nothing

Tags: pyqgis, mbtiles

I would like to create a bunch of mbtiles. The code runs and creates the file, but it is "empty", have minimal size (16kb).

```
import os
import processing
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer

raster = QgsRasterLayer("D:/Users/lnemeth/App_MbTiles/7478.tiff", 'layer')
param_dict = {
            "INPUT": raster,
            "EXTENT": raster,
            "ZOOM_MIN":10,
            "ZOOM_MAX":18,
            "OUTPUT_FILE":'D:/Users/lnemeth/App_MbTiles/try.mbtiles'
            }

processing.run("qgis:tilesxyzmbtiles", param_dict)
```

EDIT: It is a raster in EPSG:31466, I realised the problem is that the layer extent returns a `<QgsRectangle: 0 0, 0 0>` and I don't know why. If i try manually or use the exact coordinates it works.

EDIT2: I finally calculated the extent (still dont know what was the problem, at some point it just worked), now the console says the extent is invalid if i convert it to string, if i leave it like that then the same problem happens (minimal file size, no data content).

Comment: Check the return value of `processing.run()`. And are you sure you can simply pass the raster layer as extent?

Comment: @bugmenot123 I tried using the current extent, even calculate with a separate line of the code and it returns <QgsRectangle: 0 0, 0 0>, it might be the problem but I don't know why is it like this. If i do manually and use the correct values of an extent it works but as i put into the a script with the same parameters it only works when I specify the coordinates, otherwise the extent just returns those 4 zeroes.

Comment: If you create a new QGIS project, use a OSM background and load your raster file, does it display at the correct location?

Comment: @bugmenot123 Yes it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by changing the raster layer's loading method to `iface.addRasterLayer()`, now it creates the correct, not empty mbtiles.

Also I later encountered another bug, but it was solved by using older QGIS version (3.16).